# Is it a sin to chant mantras without initiation?

Tags: mantras, initiation

Is chanting any mantra without initiation a sin? What do scriptures say about this?

Comment: Do u want an answer based on Agamas?  then i can immediately post it.

Comment: @Rickross Yes definitely

Comment: It would be sin for you. Differs from person to person.

Comment: know this before asking if it is a sin. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20368/what-is-the-definition-of-sin

Comment: @Rohit. Idk how to answer that

Comment: In general yes. There are a few exceptions that don't require initiation but are enhanced with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Agamas DikshA or initiation is given utmost importance.

Mantras should be taken from a bonafide Guru only. If one chants mantra by obtaining it through some other sources (like books etc) then that is regarded as an offence.

For example, the KriyAsAra Tantram says:

> Kalpe drishtA tu yo mantram japed gurumanAsritaha |
>  SutanAsho bhavet
>   tasya phalam kinchinna vidyate ||
>
> **Meaning**
>
> The person who, without depending on a Guru ( Gurumanasitaha), chants
>   mantras by taking them from a book, gets his progeny destroyed [by doing so]
>   (sutanasho) and does not get any benefits [of the chant] either.

The KulArnava Tantram is even more strict on this:

> Pushtake likhitAnmantrAn vilokya prajapanti ye |
>  BrahmahatyAsamam
>   teshAm pAtakam parikirtitam ||
>
> **Meaning**
>
> One, who chants mantras by seeing them from books [that is not
>   obtained duely from a sampradaya Guru] commits, thereby, sin as grave
>   as BrahmahatyA (Brahminicide).
>
> **KulArnava Tantram, UlAsaha 5, Verse 22.**

So, its always better to go for Guru dikshA if you are interested in mantras.

Comment: Bro, How will one know whether he took Diksha from a bona fide Guru or not?

Comment: That is tricky. i don't think there are certain and easy ways by which we can verify. @Rohit. We can at least give it a try. if it does not work ( now whether it has worked or not we possibly won't be knowing either) then we have to realise that we need far more merits than we have accumulated till now.

Comment: @Rohit, who do you trust the most? For most people, it is their mother, father. So, ask them. If they had a guru, they will point you to him. If not, they will ask *their* elders.. grandparents, uncles, aunts. If not, go to a local temple, and ask. We do not have enough jnana/tapas/shakti to check the certificate of every guru, and even the teachings of different gurus varies. Yudhistira was posed this question by Yaksha in Mahabharata, and he says- dharma is not visible, rishis say different things, vedas seem (on the exterior) to be contradictory, so just follow path of great people (elders)

Comment: @ram Can you give link to these Yaksha prashna?

Comment: Why there is difference between taking mantra from Guru or taking mantra from book or internet. I also want to chant mantra of Lord Hanuman (coz I use to do tuesday's fast) which I got from internet. Why can't I simply chant them? Why it will be beneficial after taking it from guru only? Everyone in this sites says we should get mantra only from guru but no one explains why! I don't have any Guru and don't know where I can find. And to b honest, I don't even want any Guru. So that's mean I don't have right to chant mantras? But why? I also want to chant...

Comment: And also, we all use to chant some basic mantras like Gayatri mantra and Maha mrityunhay mantra, vishnu's mantra (om bhagwayey) and Shiva's (om namaha shivaye) and tons of more. I have seen many people chants it coz these mantras are so much popular and known to everyone. SO all chants and they didn't take it from GUru. That's means we all got sin of Brahma hatya. Almost every Indian is sinner of Brahma hatya? Really?

Comment: Why there is difference between taking mantra from Guru or taking mantra from book or internet.-- There is a lot of difference. Mantras are conscious living beings. They have death birth etc. But apart from this chaitanya or consciousness a mantra is just a combination of varnas (alphabets). If u take it from a book and not from a living Guru, then the mantra chaitanya remains latent or hidden in it. So, u won't get much benefit out of the chant. Only a Guru who has duely received the mantra from his Guru can activate the latent mantra chaitanya and give it to u.  @Rishabh

Comment: And to b honest, I don't even want any Guru. So that's mean I don't have right to chant mantras? But why? I also want to chant.--  If u want to progress in mantra marga then Guru Diksha is the first step and is inevitable. 100 out of 100 knowledgeable persons will tell u the same. Actually mantras were first spoken by Adi Guru or Shiva. There are crores of such mantras. The mantras are then passed on through disciples to their disciples and so on. We thus have the 3 lines of Gurus - Divine, Enlightened and Human. Its through these Human lines of Gurus we receive our mantras.@Rishabh

Comment: @Rishabh Also shiva panchakashra, mahamrityunjaya and gayatri are the most powerful among veda mantras. Gayatri  for eg is called the mother of Vedas. One who is initiated into gayatri mantra receives the right of chanting all the thousands of Veda mantras. So, how can u say they are basic mantras? As per scriptures only one who wears sacred thread can chant veda mantras.

Comment: That's means we all got sin of Brahma hatya. Almost every Indian is sinner of Brahma hatya? Really? --- You should take that verse as an warning not literally. The act is not recommended. Just like mothers sometimes frighten their child for their eventual benefit, Lord Shiva in that verse is doing the same. Also IMO that verse is talking about a full fledged Mantra purascharana. Few chants here and there which are triggered by devotion will not matter much. @Rishabh

Comment: I think there is too much fear because of misinterpretation of scriptures. Initiation is required because in Kaliyug, Lord Siva has locked most of the mantras (Keelit) to avoid misuse. Only a real Guru can unlock and give it to you. Regarding progeny destroyed if mantra chanted without initiation, I think it refers to the side effects of few mantras like: Baglamukhi Mantra and similar mantras.

Comment: @RKh Taking Diksha is always recommended. 100 out of 100 scriptures say that. Before Diksha a person does not get fit to perform any kind japa, puja austerities etc.

Comment: @Rickross I am posting as an answer below.

Comment: @Rickross Okay,understood that chanting mantras without Diksha is wrong.What about listening to mantras being changed by another person?

Comment: I don't think there is any harm in it .. little bit of chanting mantras should be ok too @Amethyst But taking mantras from books and trying to do Purascharan of them should not be done

Comment: Could you please give the numbering of the śloka you quoted from Kriyāsāra tantra?

Comment: Possibly I can not .. Most probably I am quoting that verse from Shaktananda Taringini or Nityotsava .. but the verse number has not been mentioned otherwise I must have mentioned it as well .. but need cross checking @Bingming

Answer (score 1):

(1) Diksha if taken from a real Guru, who is a master in that Vidya, can do wonders because of transmission of energy. A Diksha involves three: 
Disciple, Guru and Deity.

Today Diksha business is running where only two are involved, Disciple and incompetent Guru. This will not work. It is mere satisfaction that you have taken Diksha but it is of no use unless you find a real Guru, which is difficult these days.

(2) There is too much fear because of misinterpretation of scriptures. From the time these were written, many interpretations have taken place. Initiation (Diksha) is required because in Kaliyug, Lord Siva has locked most of the mantras (Keelit) to avoid misuse. Only a real Guru can unlock and give it to you. Regarding progeny destroyed if mantra chanted without initiation, I think it refers to the side effects of few mantras like: Baglamukhi Mantra and similar mantras.

(3) Mantras like Mahavidya mantra should not be attempted without a Guru, however, other Mantras need not necessarily require Diksha. Here the only difference you may feel is that after Diksha (from a real Guru), you will progress 5x or 10x times whereas alone you can progress at a Turtle speed. Also, during recitation, if you experience something, no one can guide you. Only a real Guru can guide.

Comment: If you are addressing an author of an answer, post it as a comment or use chat rooms. Answering is not the right way.

Comment: Ok, I will remove address. Rich Text features are not available in comments.

Comment: I have planned answers for your two Qs- Lalita sahsranama and what's wrong with my Yantras? after seeing those answers you may get convinced.