# Which is the correct Panchdasi mantra of Goddess Lalita?

Tags: mantras, sri-vidya, lalita

I am searching for the correct Panchdasi mantra, rather the Moola Panchdasi mantra. I referred various sites and each site has a different one:

For example, few variants are:

```
(1) क ए ई ल ह्रीं ह स क ल ह्रीं स क ल ह्रीं
(2) क ए ई ल ह्रीं ह स क ल ह्रीं स क ल ह्रीं श्रीं
(3) ह्रीं क ए ई ल ह्रीं ह स क ल ह्रीं स क ल ह्रीं
```

Which one is the Moola Mantra?

Comment: The first one is the moola one. In the latter two ones, Shreem is added in last, and hreem in beginning respectively. The first one is main one.

Comment: And may be it is ई and not इ . @Rickross kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Please post your first comment as answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: @AnuragSingh It's the Dirgha E Kara. Sorry i forgot to reply earlier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all Panchadasi refers to a 15-lettered mantra. Among the three mantras that you have given only Mantra 1 is 15-lettered the others are both 16-lettered.

And, Mantra 2= Mantra 1+ Srim and Mantra 3= Hrim + Mantra 1.

To understand how these Sri VidyA Mantras are formed we first have to understand what is a Koota and what are the three Kootas.

A Koota is a combination of Beejas (Seeds). Like the combination  "Srim Hrim Klim" (some say Aim Srim Hrim) is AdyA koota (It represents the Adi ParAshakti in Mantrik level).

The Panchadasi is formed by adding three Kootas viz: VAgbhava Koota+ KAmRaja Koota+ Shakti Koota. With each Koota being a combination of five seeds.

> VAgiswari jyAna shaktir VAgbhAbe moksharupini |
>  KAmarAje kAmakalA
>   kAmarupA kriyAtmikA ||
>  Shaktibije parA shaktiricchaiva shivarupini |
>   Evam devi trayakshari tu mahAtripurAsundari ||
>
> .................
>
> In the VAgbhava koota or beeja Devi resides as Moksharupini,
>   VAgiswari-**JyAnashakti**. In the KAmrAja koota she is KriyAtmikA
>   kAmakalA- **KriyAshakti**. And in the Shakti koota she is Sivarupini Supreme
>   **IcchAshAkti**. In this way, Goddess MahAtripurasundari's [mantra] is
>   Trayakshari (three-lettered, since each Koota is also considered as an
>   Akshara,  Panchadasi is thus three-lettered and fifteen-lettered both)
>
> **NityAshodashikArnava Tantram 4.17,18**

Thus three Kootas represent the triad- JyAnashakti-KriyAshakti-IcchAshakti. They also represent the triad Sat-Chit-Ananda. ( For translation purpose- JyAna=Knowledge, KriyA=Action and IcchA=Will)

Now, depending on how these Kootas are combined, there are several Sri VidyAs that emerge. The mantra which start with the letter Ha is HAdi VidyA. The one which starts with Ka is KAdi and the one which starts with the letter Sa is called SAdi VidyA.

A brief overview of KAdi-HAdi-SAdi Vidyas is found [here](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/srividya/kadihadi.html):

> Kadi - Hadi - Sadi
>
> [Query] Please enlighten about differences between kadi, hadi and sadi
>   vidyas?
>
> In essence, there is no difference between kAdi, hAdi or sAdi as all
>   three refer to the same brahma vastu called srI lalitA.
>
> 1. kAdi was taught by Sri Manmatha [sadAshiva – nArayaNa – Hayagriva – Agastya - Shankara bhagavatpAda etc are the Gurus], hAdi by Bhagavati
>      Lopamudra [Parameshwara – Parashakti – Lopamudra – Kalatapanandanatha
>      etc. are the Gurus] and sAdi by Sri Krodha Bhattaraka Durvasa
>      Deshikendra [Mahadeva – Rudra – Durvasa – Dharmacharya etc are the
>      Gurus].
> 2. kAdi invokes kAmeshwarAmka sthitA kAmeshwarI, hAdi invokes kAmeshwarI vibhUshitAnko kameshwaraH and sAdi invokes kAmakAmeshwarau
>      shivau. In fact, Shadanvaya Shambhavi Krama described by Acharya in
>      Saundaryalahari is chiefly for sAdi upAsakas. The subtle differences
>      in these three visualizations should be learnt directly from one's
>      Sadguru.
> 3. kAdi and hAdi panchadashi-s transform to laghu shodashi and maha/parA/guhya shodashi-s (in case of kAdi) and shuddha/hamsa
>      shodashis (in case of hAdi). There is no shodashi in sAdi karma but
>      the transformation is into saptadashI. Further, in the final step of
>      karma system, all the three paths merge into aS

The Mantra 1 is the Moola Panchadashi for the KAdi school. It was practiced by God Indra, Rishis Agastya and DurvAsa, for example.

> KAmrAja Akhyaya vidyAya bAgbhabhe kAmbijam tyaktA chandram dadyAt |
>   KAmarAje punah shivAnte chandram...... | Tena shaktikootam
>   chandrendrakAmamahAmAyAtmakam | **VidyemindropAsitA** anyAt samAnam.... ||

In these above verses from JyAnarnava Tantram, Lord Shiva gives the codes of how the Mantra 1 in your question is to be formed or decoded. This mantra is practiced by DevarAja Indra.

The same mantra without the Bindus (Bindu the Dot) was also practiced by MahAmuni Agastya.

There are several other variants of Panchadasi or Sri VidyAs which were worshipped by Moon, Manu, Kubera, Brahma, Vishnu and Shankara etc. And not all of them are exactly 15-lettered. For example the Sri VidyA that is practiced by Vishnu is having six Kootas as opposed three in regular Panchadashi.

So, to answer your question, **1) is the correct version (KAdi VidyA), while 2 and 3 are not correct**. Note that, by adding Srim Hrim beejas to the Panchadashi we can get the most powerful Shodashi mantra of Devi.

Additionally the mantra 1 in your question has GAyatri as Chandah (meter) and Sri Anandabhairva as the Rishi (Seer).

Comment: 'Srim Hrim beejas to the Panchadashi we can get the most powerful Shodashi mantra of Devi.' Hpw do you find this?.. I think Shodasi isn't known to anyone in present days (maybe there are some rare who know)

Comment: I know from the many Tantra books that i have for example the Tantra Sara. The one im talking about is called the ParibhAsik Shodashi.@Tezz

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for the beautiful explanation. How to correctly add Shreem and Hreem beejas in Mantra 1? I recite only Moola Mantra 1.

Comment: @RKh Thanks. Are u asking how to form the Shodashi from mantra 1? Sorry i can't tell you that :) BTW do u know that without initiation one **should not** chant mantras let alone something like Sri Vidya mantras?

Comment: @Rickross Its Ok if you can't disclose. Initiation may infuse power in the mantra depending upon the level of Guru however, I feel, it is not necessary. Mantras themselves contain powers. Guru can only guide you with any specific method or ritual. Devotion is more important. I may be wrong. Today, neither you can find true masters easily, who can really initiate you and unfold the secrets, nor true seekers. There is one incident how I came to know about Panchdasi. I am only interested in Panchdasi only which you have advised that first one is the correct moola mantra.

Comment: Its great that you have devotion for Mother Lalita. So half the job is already done. For the rest to be accomplished you will definitely need a Guru who will be none other than Mother Lalita but in disguise.:) And Mantra Yoga is not Bhakti Yoga. Mantra Yoga is basically Jyana + Karma. You will be amazed to know the intricacies of Mantra science. Mantras are living beings, they will have birth-death and related impurities, they will sleep, they will have other impurities. Dasha Samaskaras and Dipani etc are thus needed to be performed. --

Comment: *    Now who other than Mother Lalita herself (in form of ur living Guru) can teach u all these? In Mantra yoga success can not be achieved with Guru. How will u know some preliminary things related to it like- Viniyogah, Nyasa etc? Lord Shiva clearly says without Nyasa japa bears no fruits. Without knowing Viniyogah of a mantra there is no success. I know finding Guru may be difficult but not that difficult as it seems, If u are trying hard already just try a lil bit harder..:) @RKh

Comment: Also all scriptures say doing mantra japa on ur own by looking from books is a sin. For eg see this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/is-it-a-sin-to-chant-mantras-without-initiation/20367#20367 .. So u should take this as orders of Mother Lalita and find a Guru. If u want to follow the Bhakti way then simply do nama japa or simple stotras. @RKh Also do not think that i am trying to discourage you. If it was my brother-sister or any near and dear ones doing the same like you then also i would have always warned them.

Comment: @Rickross Searching for a Guru can lead to disaster in today's time. It is better to pray to Goddess and wait for the right Guru to come to you.

Comment: @Rickross Coming to your second comment. I am not against the methods: Viniyog, Nyasa etc. These definitely have meaning but when you don't know you can chant "Lalita Sahasranam" first followed by any mantra. Anything incomplete is completed if done after Lalita Sahasranam. I have experienced the guidance by Goddess in the last few months. I don't know much about Sri Vidya, but some or the other guidance Goddess is giving in dreams.

Comment: Ok @RKh that's great to know that you got that instruction in the dreams. i would interpret that dream as Goddess asking you to take a Panchadashi Diksha. You can look for Gurus who give Sri Vidya Dikshas online. Or you can wait for Sri Lalita's grace.

Comment: @Rickross Yes may be. I am waiting for the Goddess to send the right Guru. Till that time I am offering the Japa to her and praying for Guru.

Comment: Any reference for adya koota

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yes there are plenty of references. For eg- Commentary on Kularnava, Tantrasara, Shaktanada Tarangini, Mahanirvana etc..