# Which mantras of Krishna and Vishnu does not require initiation and does not have any rules to follow?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, mantras, japa

Mantras of Krishna and Vishnu which does not require any initiation, does not have any rules to follow, can be chanted anytime and anywhere. Please don't include Hare Krishna Maha mantra in your answer as it requires initiation according to Radha Tantra. All the mantras should be backed by scriptural references, download links (if any). A humble request to people who are Krishna and Vishnu devotees or people knowledgable of mantras to answer this question. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: All mantras will more or less require initiation.. reading stotras will be the better option for uninitiated persons..

Comment: @Rickross Yes Stotras are also a good option, still there are some limitations...There might be some mantras which does not require initiation. Lets check as there are vast number of scriptures available.

Comment: Yes might be there..

Answer (score 6):

There are thousands of Mantras in the Vedas, but the kind of Mantras you are looking for are not to be found in them.

Agamas or Tantras have plenty of them.

Bu for the Tantric Mantras Guru Diksha is required.

Lord Shiva says:

> TasmAt siddhantam samprApya sampradAyAdihetubhih |
>   **AntarenopodeshtAram mantrAh syur nishphalA yatah** ||
>
> *KulArnava Tantram 14.4*

It basically means, "without Guru Upadesha, all traditional knowledge, philosophies and Mantras fail to bear fruit".

I find many Mantras (like we discussed in chat) of Vishnu and Krishna in the Tantrasara. They are from SanatkumAra Tantra, Gautamiya Tantram, NArada PancharAtram etc.. So, they will all require initiation.

Also, as shown in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20367/4732), chanting a Tantric Mantra without proper initiation is condemned:

> Kalpe drishtA tu yo mantram japed gurumanAsritaha |
>   SutanAsho bhavet
>   tasya phalam kinchinna vidyate ||
>
> The person who, without depending on a Guru ( Gurumanasitaha), chants
>   mantras by taking them from a book, gets his progeny destroyed [by
>   doing so] (sutanasho) and does not get any benefits [of the chant]
>   either.

Now, the Puranas also have few Mantras. What about them?

From the Devi Bhagavata PurAna's last chapter of the last Book:

> So for the satisfaction of one’s own S’akti, all can read this,
>   without contradicting each other. **Never any woman nor any S’ûdra, is
>   to read this herself or himself, even out of ignorance; rather they
>   should hear this from the mouth of a Brâhmana. This is the rule of the
>   S’âstras.**

So, what it says those who do not have Vedic initiation, should not read the Purana and thus they can not chant the Puranic Mantras as well.

Similarly, the VyAsa Smriti says:

> Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, and Vaishyas are called the. twice-born. Their
>   first births take place when they a^re delivered of their mother's
>   womb ; their second,when they duly accept the Gayatri Mantra from
>   their preceptors. (21)
>
> Thus made twice-born, and free from all other faults, **they become
>   entitled to study the Vedas, Smritis and Puranas.** (22)

So, what it says, even for reciting the Mantras mentioned in the Puranas, one needs to get a Vedic initiation. And for Agamic Mantras a Guru Upadesha will be required.

So, i am afraid, no such Mantras are there.

Answer (score 4):

**There are no such mantras.** All mantras require initiation from a recognized Parampara, as chapter 10 of the Garga Samhita says:

> Vamana, Brahma, Ananta Sesha and Sanaka Kumara will appear as brahmanas by the order of Visnu, for the preservation of eternal righteousness in kali yuga. Visnu Swami, Madhvacarya, Ramanuja and Nimbaditya will appear respectively as a portion of Vamana, Brahma, Ananta Sesha and Sanaka Kumara. These saviours will be the establishers of the four authorised and empowered spiritual channels of disciplic succession in the period calculated from the reign of King Vikrama in 54 B.C. subsequently through the present era of kali yuga. These four authorised and empowered spiritual channels of disciplic succession are to be fully accepted by all beings; **as any word, combination of words or formulation of sounds frequencies, invoked or addressed, audible or inaudible, secret or revealed, ancient or contemporary, outside their auspices prove to have absolutely no efficacy**.

Comment: thanks but are you 100% sure about this. For example Namo gopijana-vallabhabhyam and Gopijana-vallabha-charanau sharanam prapadye mantras from sanat kumara Samhita are such type of mantras which has no rules and not bound by any Sampradyas. These mantras are told by Sadashiva to Narada Muni.

Comment: @Salvation Those are from Pancharatra Agamas and thus require Samashrayanam, the initiation ritual for Pancharatra.

Comment: But when i read the translation it says-In texts 36-41, Lord Sadashiva continues: “One who either with faith or without faith once chants this five-word mantra resides among Lord Krishna’s gopi-beloveds. Of this there is no doubt. In chanting these mantras there is no need of purshcharana, nyasa, ari-shuddhi, mitra-shuddhi, or other kinds of purification. In chanting these mantras there is no restriction of time or place. All, from the lowest outcaste to the greatest sage, are eligible to chant this mantra. Women, shudras, and all others are eligible. The paralyzed, mute etc

Comment: The above list is a very long list. but it is easily available in internet.

Comment: I have read the other slokas as well. These 2 mantras does need pancanga-nyasa and the kara-nyasa. one should perform them both with the bija-syllable. So these 2 mantras can be chanted after these rituals. Still there might be some mantras of Krishna and Vishnu which does not have any rules and no initiation is needed.

Comment: Pancharatra Mantras generally don't have caste restrictions, they can be freely chanted by low-caste people, women, etc. But they still require Diksha, and that Diksha is the Samashrayanam ritual, aka Pancha Samskaram.

Comment: But nāma mantras don't require initiation right? For e.g. chanting 'Rāma', 'Kṛṣṇa', 'Durgā', Śiva etc.?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one mantra that doesn't require any initiation or diksha ie
Ram or राम

विना एव दीक्षा पुरश्चर्यां विना एव हि।

विना एव न्यास विदिशा जपमात्रेण सिद्धिदः।।

(Shuka samhita) of narrator of shrimadbhagwat puran shri shuka acharya

For chanting of ram naam, there is no need of diksha, nor there is any need to feed Brahmins, nor there is such need to mantra anusthan.

Again in padmapuran

न देश काल नियमः शौच अशौच विनिर्णयः।

परं संकीर्तनाद् एवं राम रामेति मुच्यते।।

Whenever or wherever whether you are clean or unclean, anybody can chant greatest sankirtan mantra ie ram naam

Answer (score 0):

The Hare Krishna Mahamantra prescribed by Mahaprabhu does not need initiation or purascharan etc but gives whatever one desires, according to Chaitanyabhagavat and Chaitanyacharitamrita. Mahaprabhu Himself declared this and this is supported by the scriptures like the kalisantaranopanishad etc

Comment: Please cite the verse with the verse number from the Upanishad, preferably sharing a link to the same. Thanks.

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali-Saṇṭāraṇa_Upaniṣad

Comment: I meant include the exact verse+verse number+link to verse in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: The wiki itself says that Chaitanya himself was initiated into the Hare Krishna Mahamantra, so the reference you gave, contradicted your own point 