# Alternative to mantras

Tags: scripture, shiva, krishna, mantras, deity

Chanting mantras without initiation is not fruitful. I found few references:

- Sin of chanting mantras without [initiation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/is-it-a-sin-to-chant-mantras-without-initiation).
- Mantras without initiation not [possible](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24218/which-mantras-of-krishna-and-vishnu-does-not-require-initiation-and-does-not-hav).

I read shiv [puran](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226686.html)(English translation by JJ Shastri)

> 64. This mantra is not ineffective even if it is not properly imparted by the preceptor. It is not ineffective even in the case of persons
>     not caring for good conduct and who have not purified the six paths.

Here lord says its not ineffective so it dose not mean it will be effective. May be no negative effects.

Now the best spiritual practise can aspirants do?

- Is it chanting names of deity? 108 Names/Shotas or 1008 Names/Shotras?
- And adding few niyamas once a aspirant gets fluency and pronunciation.

Answers with some references will be appreciated.

Comment: Beeja mantras without initiation aren't fruitful because they don't have been charged. Just as there is *attunement* in *reiki*, similar *attunement* is required by the Guru to the disciple for it to work. It's not really the mantra that yields siddhi, because it is possible to have different mantras do the exact same thing, so pronunciation isn't a big issue either in most of the cases (e.g. Shabar mantras). But the diksha is more important, otherwise chant doesn't help. You can do a few things 1. Activate Mantras via Yoga 2. Stotram of the deity 3. Practice yama/nimayas 4. Read scriptures

Comment: Thanks @User29449 for comment. Few follow up questions ?
1. Activate mantras via yoga can you elaborate?/or share reference.
2. Can you share some reference of yama/niyamas, relevant in kali yuga?

Comment: 1. For the sake of example, say - the beeja mantra *om* is used for enlightenment. It is popularly known as [*Pranava Yoga*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pranava_yoga). [Refer to Yoga Sutras of Patanjali, Chapter 2]. 2. Yama, Nimayas are always the same for all yugas, Refer to Patanjali for it. Alternatively, the foundations of Yog - Karm Yog, Bhakti Yog, and Gyan Yog is always enough. If you know Advaita Vedanta and Yoga philosophy, then read - Uttara Gita by Krishna. It has knowledge of Raja Yoga too (which is optional for only advanced practitioners).

Comment: Thanks a lot. @User29449