# Can a person who isn't initiated chant mantra of his Ishta Devata?

Tags: mantras, guru

For example, my Ishta Devata is Vishnu so can I chant these mantras:

1. "ॐ नमोः नारायणाय. ॐ नमोः भगवते वासुदेवाय" / "oṃ namoḥ nārāyaṇāya. oṃ namoḥ bhagavate vāsudevāya"
2. “ऊँ नारायणाय विद्महे।वासुदेवाय धीमहि। तन्नो विष्णु प्रचोदयात्” / “ūm̐ nārāyaṇāya vidmahe।vāsudevāya dhīmahi। tanno viṣṇu pracodayāt”

Source of this question: http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=525

> Get the Mantra initiation from your Guru. Or pray to your Ishta Devata and start doing Japa of the particular Mantra, if you find it difficult to get a Guru.

-

> You can select any Mantra for Purascharana. Your Guru Mantra or Ishta Mantra is the best. Sandhya time...

Comment: Scriptures usually don't approve this practice. See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/is-it-a-sin-to-chant-mantras-without-initiation/20367#20367) for knowing what the Tantras say on this topic. It's my personal opinion though that you can still follow the Swamiji here.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for replying. Actually I have a few months until I am 18 and start college and so it would take a bit while to start my spiritual journey. Do you think I should wait till that time?

Comment: Yes you should wait. Do one thing at a time.

Comment: @Rickross Alright, I will wait till then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this person attempted to ask and answer the question in the question.