# Can someone chant this mantra without initiation if close to death

Tags: mantras, vedic-chanting, health

I come acroess [a twitter post](https://twitter.com/HinduMediaWiki/status/1382926683515228160)

> For ones with Covid +ve chant this mantra for self or others 108 by
> energizing water in a kalash.
>
> "Aim Hreem Shreem Sarva Vyādhi Prasamani Sarva Mrutyu Nivarinyayi
> Namaha Shree Lalithambika Pahimam Rakshamam"

Few people were saying that beej mantra should only be chanted after intiation , which is well known fact. So there was one disclaimer at the end of the post.

> Adding to it this is a Sharnagati nama mantra with Beej Samputikaran.
> Use it for Pandemic situation only and discontinue further once things
> are at place.
>
> A rare condition where we have shared a mantra on our Tweets seeing
> the need of the hour.

So my doubt is can this mantra can be chanted without intiation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a sin to chant mantras without initiation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/is-it-a-sin-to-chant-mantras-without-initiation)

Comment: actually I am aware that beej mantra cant be chanted without initiation. But the above mantra is differnt in the sense that its Sharnagati nama mantra with Beej Samputikaran.