# Can panchadashi mantra chanted without initiation?

Tags: sri-vidya

Some say it can be chanted without initiation and some say it can't be. Please resolve this query of mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a sin to chant mantras without initiation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/is-it-a-sin-to-chant-mantras-without-initiation)

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is not recommended at all to chant any mantras without initiation. Please refer to [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20367/4732) for some verses.

Qualification (or Adhikara) of chanting mantras is obtained only after initiation.

Quoting from the article ["Srividya Diksha Vivechini"](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/2021/03/12/srividya-diksha-vivechini/):

> Srividya is a Shastra in itself and like every other Shastra, has the
> associated anubandha chatuShTaya – adhikAra, abhidheya, sambandha and
> prayojana. adhikAra describes the qualifications required to obtain
> initiation into shrIvidyA. Abhidheya is the subject matter of
> Srividya. Sambandha describes its relation with other Shastras.
> Prayojana describes the fruits obtained by studying Srividya. A guru
> should understand these four concepts well. As Srividya Shastra in
> essence advocates Nivrtti, it is also termed parA vidyA. Srividya is
> moksha Shastra or the science of liberation, which can be approached
> in five different levels, the upAsyas for which are lalitA,
> mahAtripurasundarI, rAjarAjeshwarI, parA bhattArikA and ahaMtA or
> sadakhyA. All these are generally termed as `shrI’. That Shastra which describes` shrI’ is called shrIvidyA. Or, shrIyate sarvairiti shrIH –
> she who is worshipped by all is shrI.
>
> As there is no difference between Brahma Jnana and Brahmi Bhava
> [brahmavidApnoti param], there is no difference between the upAsya
> [shrI] and it’s vidyA. Thus, Srividya refers to that vidyA or mantra
> which is of the form of shrI and refers to shrI. Also, as described in
> Siddha Yamala, Parashakti has two chief forms: Rakta Kali and Shyama
> Kali. Rakta Kali is called Vidya Rajni and Shyama is associated with
> Dakshina Kali and Sundari. Thus, Srividya refers to Sri + Vidya –
> Srividya, which encompasses the worship of both these forms and hence
> of Purna Parabrahma Shakti. Also, that vidya which has the ramA bIja
> as its core is referred to as Srividya. That which grants shrI i.e.
> purushartha chatushtaya is called Srividya. The term Srividya has been
> explained in 108 ways by Brahmasri Sri Tadepalli Veeraraghava
> Shastrigal.

In his book [Japa Yoga](http://japa-yoga.org/japa.pdf), Swami Sivananda also advises against chanting Sri Vidya mantras without initiation.

> Repetition of Subrahmanya-Mantra 'Om Sri Saravanabhavaya Namah' will
> give you success in any under taking and make you glorious. It will
> drive off evil influences and evil spirits. Repetition of Sri
> Hanuman-Mantra. 'Om Sri Hanumate Namah' will bestow victory and
> strength. Repetition of Panchadasakshara and Shodasakshara (Sri Vidya)
> will give you wealth, power, freedom, etc. It will give you whatever
> you want. **You must learn this Vidya from a Guru alone.**

> Sri-Vidya is the great Mantra of Tripurasundari or Bhuvanesvari or
> Mahamaya. It is also called the Panchadasi or the Panchadasakshari,
> for it is formed of fifteen letters. In its developed form it consists
> of sixteen letters and is called Shodasi or the Shodasakshari. **The
> aspirant should directly get initiation of this Mantra from a Guru,
> and should not start reading it for himself or doing Japa of it, of
> his own accord**. This is a very powerful Mantra and, when it is not
> properly repeated, it may harm the Upasaka. So it is imperative that
> it should be got directly from a Guru who has got Siddhi of this
> Mantra.